# Generalized type constraints with Swift

Tags: swift, type-constraints, generics, swift-extensions

As an exercise, I'm trying to extend `Array` in Swift to add a `sum()` member function. This should be type safe in a way that I want a call to `sum()` to compile only if the array holds elements that can be added up.

I tried a few variants of something like this:

```
extension Array {

    func sum<U : _IntegerArithmeticType where U == T>() -> Int {
        var acc = 0
        for elem in self {
            acc += elem as Int
        }
        return acc
    }

}
```

The idea was to say, “OK, this is a generic function, the generic type must be something like an `Int`, and must also be the same as `T`, the type of the elements of the array”. But the compiler complains: “Same-type requirement make generic parameters U and T equivalent”. That's right, and they should be, with the additional contraint `T : _IntegerArithmeticType`.

Why isn't the compiler letting me do this? How can I do it?

(I know that I should later fix how things are added up and what the return type exactly is, but I'm stuck at the type constraint for now.)

Comment: It is (currently) not possible to extend Array with methods that require the elements to be of a restricted type. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630476/swift-array-insert-generics (both of them might qualify as a duplicate).

Comment: You wrote “(currently)”. Has anyone heard whispers it may change soon?

Comment: I *think* that I read in devforums.apple.com that this is a known issue and might change in the future, but I am not 100% sure. I will give you the link if I find it again.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post the least bad workaround I found as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Martin R's comment, this is not currently possible. The thing I'm tempted to use in this particular situation would be an explicit passing of a `T -> Int` conversion function:

```
extension Array {

    func sum(toInt: T -> Int?) -> Int {
        var acc = 0
        for elem in self {
            if let i = toInt(elem) {
                acc += i
            }
        }
        return acc
    }

}
```

Then I can write stuff like this:

```
func itself<T>(t: T) -> T {
    return t
}

let ss = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "five"].sum { $0.toInt() }
let si = [1, 2, 3, 4].sum(itself)
```

An explicit function has to be passed, though. The `(itself)` part can of course be replaced by `{ $0 }`. (Others have called the `itself` function `identity`.)

Note that an `A -> B` function can be passed when `A -> B?` is needed.